# How to test the textbox value in the Android JUnit test

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, testcase

i have just created login screen project.I wrote the testcase for that.I dont know how to enter the text in textbox in JUnit test case. i just did like this

```
         public void testlogin() {
    final String n1 = "adithi";
    final String p1 = "adithi";
    String name, pass;
    editUname.clearComposingText();
    editPswd.clearComposingText();
    TouchUtils.tapView(this, editUname);
    sendKeys("adithi");
    TouchUtils.tapView(this, editPswd);
    sendKeys("adithi");

    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

          public void run() {


            signinbtn.performClick();
          }
        }); 

        name = editUname.getText().toString();

        pass = editPswd.getText().toString();

    Log.e("name",name); 
    Log.e("Password",pass);
    assertEquals(n1, name);
    assertEquals(p1, pass);
}
```

the testcase result is

```
 junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: expected:<adithi> but was:<>
 at com.firstpageTest.Test.testlogin(Test.java:126)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:204)
 at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:194)
 atandroid.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTest
    (ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.ja
 atandroid.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTest
   (ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:186)
  at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:169)
  at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:154)
  at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:520)
  at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1447)
```

please guide me.

Comment: jeez! You've edited your question and changed your code! I can sorta confirm UI text is going null somewhere after you `performClick()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a simple one and  I have done a small mistake in giving input to JUnit.we must give as

```
       sendKeys("A D I T H I");
```

It works now.

Answer (score 0):

Note. I'm not a Java person but..

Your test is failing because well its failing, your code is not running as **you** expected.It says `expected:<Karthika> but was:<>`

So the string from your UI is probably `null`. You're putting the string `Karthika` in the UI, then your test expects both strings to be `adithi`, but it fails saying it was null.

1. Somewhere the text in your UI goes null.
2. I **think** it should be `assertEquals(actualvar, whatyouexpect);` like `assertEquals(name, n1);`

Comment: i checked it,it is assertEquals(String expected,String actual);

Comment: Its going null or blank somewhere then. When/How is `testlogin` running? And what does `performclick()` do?

Comment: i think sendkeys("") is not the method  to enter the textbox value.but i cant guess the method to give that.